# socket.io doesn't seem to be starting and doesn't recognize io.configure method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, typeerror

I am trying to get socket.io running with node/express (I have done this countless times - so I am pretty baffled). When I try to configure socket.io with the `io.configure` method I get an error:

```
io.configure(function() {
   ^
TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'configure'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yz/webdev/ground/app.js:377:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

My code is exactly how it says to do it on [socket.io](http://socket.io) - but I'll post it just in case:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8000);

//other declarations
app.use(...
passport.use(...

//some routes
app.get(...
app.post(...

io.configure(function() {
  io.set('transports', ['websocket','xhr-polling','flashsocket']);
  io.set('flash policy port', 10843);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('message', function (data) {
    ...
  });
});
```

The error gets thrown at the `io.configure` method - I have done this before with other sites, I don't understand whey it isn't working now. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I was just reading [here](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/) that `io.configure` doesn't exist anymore - however, I can't seem to get it working the new way either. Here is my new code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
//var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var socket = require('socket.io')({
  'transports': ['websocket','xhr-polling','flashsocket'],
  'flash policy port': 10843
});

var io = socket.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('message', function (data) {
     ...
  });
});
```

I'm not getting any errors, socket.io just doesn't seem to be starting.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `io` to a server, which is causing the problems when you attempt to call functions on `io` which are available from `socket.io`.  Try replacing this line:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

With this line:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

The [socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/) list a couple of configuration patterns you can take advantage of, and it is possible to create a server using `socket.io`.  But since you're already creating a server, you shouldn't need to do it with `socket.io`.

Comment: I did what you suggested, and socket.io still seems to just be dead - no console message saying it starts up.

Comment: I am using socket.io to retieve data from a flash game to be posted on a website - that is why I need socket.io listening on the server.

Comment: io.configure doesn't exist anymore

Comment: I see the update, but it still has the `var io = socket.listen(server);`.  Try replacing with what I said above, or using the example in the docs: http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4

Comment: i tried the new example from the docs for express 4 exactly and it still doesn't work.

Comment: i realized that it is now `io.on` not `io.sockets.on` - i changed that too - but it still isnt working.

Comment: I am trying to get a flash game I made to send data through the socket (from actionscript - the flash language) to the node server - I know that everything works on the flash side...but I can't seem to get the socket server to start - so that it can receive the data from the flash game - I thought io.configure may have had something to do with it - but then I realized that it is deprecated as of socket.io version 1.0 - so now I don't know where to go, or why it isnt working - other than looking through socket.io docs.

Comment: I mean what is the error you are getting on starting the server.  The original question seemed to be around starting the server, or at least on the `io.configure` function, but we've worked through that.  It's hard to understand what is in your app file and what's not working now.

Comment: I just got it working - thanks for your help - socket.io 1.0 doesn't have info messages when the server starts...i did a console.log upon connection and it showed up...thanks for your help.

Comment: i still can't get data from flash side though - (im sending from a mobile app that is sending data to port 8000 of the server) - i am reading about engine.io - its new as of version 1.0 for socket.io, can't figure out how to use it